# Stable Line Custom Component

Tags: java, custom-component

I used following code to create a custom component to draw edges of graphs, but the component has weird behaviors. sometimes it appear right, but sometimes it doesn't appear.
I looked other custom component samples but couldn't find where is the problem.
So the question is where is the problem?

```
public class EdgeLine extends JPanel
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5820537358240087280L;

public final Edge edge;

private int cHeight;
private int cWidth;

private Line2D line;

public EdgeLine(Edge edge)
{
    Point firstLocation = edge.firstVertex.location;
    Point secondLocation = edge.secondVertex.location;

    this.edge = edge;
    cWidth = Math.abs(firstLocation.y - secondLocation.y);
    cHeight = Math.abs(firstLocation.x - secondLocation.x);

    setSize(cHeight, cWidth);
    this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

    int xPoint = Math.min(firstLocation.x, secondLocation.x);
    int yPoint = Math.min(firstLocation.y, secondLocation.y);

    setLocation(new java.awt.Point(xPoint, yPoint));

    line = new Line2D.Float(firstLocation.x - xPoint, firstLocation.y - yPoint
            , secondLocation.x - xPoint, secondLocation.y - yPoint);
}

private void drawLine(Graphics2D graphic)
{
    graphic = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
    graphic.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));
    graphic.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    graphic.draw(line);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (isOpaque()) 
    { //paint background
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    Graphics2D graphic = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    drawLine(graphic);
    graphic.dispose();
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(cHeight, cWidth);
    return dim;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about how it looks when it appears right, and how it looks when it doesn't?

Comment: I also have a custom component for vertexes that extends from JLabel. when I double click on two of vertexes, It should add an EdgeLine between them. It happen but doesn't appear. But when I double click on one of those vertexes the Edges of that vertex appear. and when I double click on another place, it disappears again!

Comment: I should mention that the holder of this components are a JPanel. and I had to set layout to null to be able set explicit place of components.

Comment: Why do you keep creating new Graphics2D instances? You create one in your paintComponent method, pass it to drawLine() where you ignore it and create another new one.

Comment: thanks. that was the problem. I used many solutions, so that line was there from before. I forgot to remove that.

Comment: Well done @FredK. Perhaps if you wrote that up in an Answer the OP might select it as correct :-)